# What is read cache in "[sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA"?

Tags: linux, cache, hard-drive, disk-cache

I'm trying to figure out what the `read cache` part of the following message refers to:

> [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO
>   or FUA

Is it "IDE drive's read-lookahead feature (usually ON by default)" as treated by hdparm?

If it's not, how can this be turned off?

Comment: Hi Poige. I suspect the -'ve votes are because what's in the title of your question isn't actually in the question. I'll tidy it up a bit for you.

Comment: @Mark Henderson♦, can you respond via moder's tool?

Comment: New badge, Gold badge: You've earned the "Famous Question" badge (Question with 10,000 views) for "What is read cache in “[sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA”?"., earned on Server Fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found out proper tool to control this cache: `sdparm`.

It looks like as not having any relation to read-ahead cache. Also, seemingly rare SATA drive is able to unset this bit.

Comment: What is your problem anyway? What do you want to achieve when meddling with this settings?

Comment: There's no problem at all, I just paid attention to this very dmesg's message. Also, I thought that turning read cache off in favor of write-cache could be a worth-doing thing if that would increase write cache accordingly (OS caches reading anyway).

Comment: [Here](https://linux.goeszen.com/what-is-doesnt-support-dpo-or-fua.html) I learned that these are more obscure features of the ATAPI protocol most drivers won't support anyway. Don't know why the devs decided to put this debug message in.